# Reading text file and returning most popular name for that year

Tags: python-3.x

So here's the text file I'm working with:

```
AK,F,1910,Mary,14
AK,F,1910,Annie,12
AK,F,1910,Anna,10
AK,F,1910,Margaret,8
AK,F,1910,Helen,7
AK,F,1910,Elsie,6
```

The text file contains every state. It continues up until the 2000s. For every year, the gender M and F is listed, the first name at the beginning of each year is the most popular year. For example, Mary is the most popular baby name in 1910.
 My code should return something like this:

```
Enter state: ny
Enter gender: f
Enter start year: 2004
Enter end year: 2007
Top female names for NY between 2004-2007:
In 2004 Emily occurred the most at 1590 times
In 2005 Emily occurred the most at 1444 times
In 2006 Emily occurred the most at 1317 times
In 2007 Isabella occurred the most at 1425 times
Emily occurred consecutively the most in this range at 3 time/s
```

I already have a lot of this program written. I just need some advice on how to  returns a list of Name objects representing the top name for each year in
the range.

Comment: So where is that code, and what exactly is the problem with it? This isn't a code-writing service.

Comment: @Adam: Please vote for my answer if it helped you in your assignment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is how you could do (here it is with 2.7.8, I do not have 3.x on this machine):

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

data = '''-,-,1970,John,-
-,-,1970,John,-
-,-,1970,Paul,-
-,-,2014,Bob,-
-,-,2014,Mary,-
-,-,2014,Mary,-'''

temp = defaultdict(list)

for record in (line.split(',') for line in data.splitlines()):
  y = record[2]
  n = record[3]
  temp[y].append(n)

results = [(k, Counter(v).most_common(1)) for k,v in temp.items()]
```

[('2014', [('Mary', 2)]), ('1970', [('John', 2)])]

```
for year,r in results:
  if int(year) in valid:
   print('In {0} the name {1} occured the most ({2} times)'.format(year, r[0][0], r[0][1]))
```

In 2014 the name Mary occured the most (2 times)

In 1970 the name John occured the most (2 times)

Comment: If you need to get all the counts of each year, remove .most_common, if you need the top 3 of each year, use .most_common(3)